# Flip of tails after two consecutive heads

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

A fair coin is flipped $82$ times. What is the expected number of times that a flip of tails is followed immediately by two consecutive flips of heads?

My try:
I actually tried to find the distribution as follows:

Let $X$ be number of times the coin is tossed and the last three tosses will be $HHT$
So we have:
$$\begin{aligned}
&P(X=3)=\frac{1}{2^{3}} \\
&P(X=4)=\frac{2}{2^{4}} \\
&P(X=5)=\frac{4}{2^{5}} \\
&P(X=6)=\frac{7}{2^{6}} \\
&P(X=7)=\frac{12}{2^{7}}
\end{aligned}$$

If we observe the numerators are terms of the series:
$$1,2,4,7,12,26,...$$ but i don't see any pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We define $X_i$ to be an indicator function where it takes value $1$ if the toss outcome of the $i$-th, $(i+1)$-th, and $(i+2)$-th outcome are $T,H,H$ respectively.

The desired outcome is then $\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{80} X_i]=\sum_{i=1}^{80} \mathbb{E}[X_i]$

Hence the expectation is $80 \cdot \frac18=10$